# Pandas "type of <class 'str'>"

Tags: python, string, pandas, indexing

I am writing a program using data from the Olympics.

The question being asked is:

> Which country has won the most gold medals in summer games?

The answer is:

> the USA

These are some of the variables and data points for reference:

```
# Summer  Gold  Silver  Bronze  Total medals
United Arab Emirates 8  1   0   0   1
United States   26  976 757 666 2399
Uruguay 20  2   2   6   10
```

The function below should return a single string value but instead it is returning a pandas Data Frame

```
def answer_one():
    return df.loc[df['Gold'] == df['Gold'].max()]
```

How can I correct this function?

Comment: Hypothetically, if there was a tie for summer gold medals between two countries, what would you expect your function to return?

Answer (score 1):

Do this instead:

```
def answer_one():
    return list(df.loc[df['Gold'] == df['Gold'].max()].index)
```

That should give you a list of countries with max golds if there are ties. If there are no ties, it will just give a list containing one entry: in your case, the result will be `['US']`.

Answer (score 0):

If Country name is your index column this should do the trick:

`df.loc[df['Gold'].idxmax()]`

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

you can try this. It worked to me

df.Gold.idxmax()

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
def answer_one():
    return df[df['Gold'] == df['Gold'].max()].index[0]
```